# Bad spacing of table inside subfigure

Tags: tables, subfloats

I have a figure setup as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\subfigure[Part 1]
{
   \includegraphics*[totalheight=2in,origin=c]{ost100}
}
\subfigure[Part 2]
{
   \includegraphics*[totalheight=2in,origin=c]{bay}
}
\subfigure[Part 3]
{
   \small
   \begin{tabular}{| l | c | r | r | } \hline
   {...}
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
}
\caption{The main experiment.\label{f:main}}
\end{figure*}
```

For some reason, my table ends up shifted far below the images in part 1 and 2, with about a 1/2 inch margin above it. Shrinking the images doesn't change this. Any idea what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete. You should consider using `subfig` instead.

Comment: My collaborators made the subfigure decision. Can you recommend good documentation/examples. A quick test didn't let subfig and subfigure play nicely together.

Comment: The subfigure and subfig packages are incompatible, so you can only use one of them. It's not clear to me why your collaborators made a decision using a package which is obsolete (and was superseeded by the subfig package of the same author) for more than 7 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`tabular`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#tabular) environment accepts an optional parameter for alignment with respect to the current line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Part 1]{%
      \includegraphics*[totalheight=1in,origin=c]{ost100}
    }
    \subfloat[Part 2]{%
      \includegraphics*[totalheight=1in,origin=c]{bay}
    }
    \subfloat[Part 3]{%
      \small
      \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|r|} \hline
        Table head & Table head \\ \hline
        Some Values & Some Values \\
        Some Values & Some Values \\
        Some Values & Some Values \\
        Some Values & Some Values \\
        Some Values & Some Values \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{The main experiment.}\label{fig:main}
  \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Note that the example uses the [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package instead oth the obsolete [subfigure](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) (see comments).

The `demo` option for the graphicx package was necessary because your graphics files where not present. Just drop it later.

Comment: I didn't know about the [b] parameter. That fixed the problem. (Of course, everyone is right -- we shouldn't be using subfigure, but I'll let my co-author deal with that.)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\subfloat[Part 1]{\includegraphics*[width=0.3\linewidth]{ost100}}\hfill
\subfloat[Part 2]{\includegraphics*[width=0.3\linewidth]{bay}}   \hfill
\subfloat[Part 3]{\small
   \begin{tabular}[b]{| l | c | r | r | } \hline
    foo&bar&baz&foo \\\hline
    foo&bar&baz&foo \\\hline
    foo&bar&baz&foo \\\hline
   \end{tabular}}
\caption{The main experiment.\label{f:main}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]