# In beamer, figure and table side by side

Tags: floats

I have 6 figures and 1 table.
I plan to arrange them as follows,
in the first line, there are 4 figures side by side.
in the second line, there are [figure figure table].

```
\begin{document}


\begin{block}{Results}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{figure} % "[t!]" placement specifier just for this example
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c_cs.eps} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{soft.eps}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c_kernel.eps}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C_gl_abs_lambda=10-3.eps}
\end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C_mtl_hinge_lambda=10-3.eps}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C_mmmf_hinge_lambda=10-5.eps}
end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}
\begin{table}
%\vspace{0.3cm}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cccc}
    \toprule
   per iteration (s)                      &\vtop{\hbox{\strut Dimensionality}\hbox{\strut Reduction}}   & Linear SVM  &Kernel SVM  \\\midrule
FISTA   &  $5$         &  $21$ & $ 0.1052$ \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}\vspace{-0.3cm}\caption{Running time}\label{tab rt}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}


\end{block}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this is of help for you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10383 But I would use `subcaption` and not `subfig`

Comment: Will the subfigures have captions?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it's not recommended to use `subcaption` and `beamer`.

Comment: And which should be the alignment? Can you add a description or an image of the desired output?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, Thank you for your comment. I will learn how to use dummies.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, latex has many good package. I means we can get a result by different ways.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: good to know, thanks. I am not that much into `beamer`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one option using `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Results}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}~%
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}~%
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-b}~%
\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.9\linewidth}{XX}
\toprule
header1 & header2 \\
\midrule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If subcaptions are required for the subfigures, you can load the `subfig` package with the `caption=false` option and use its `\subfloat` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Results}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[the first subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}}~%
\subfloat[the second subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[the third subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}}~%
\subfloat[the fourth subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[the fifth subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-b}}~%
\subfloat[the sixth subfigure]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.9\linewidth}{XX}
\toprule
header1 & header2 \\
\midrule
text & text \\
text & text \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But there is no way to add the caption for each figure. But anyway, I can write a sentence to describe the figures because of it is poster.

Comment: @Vivian in some minutes I'll update the answer providing an option with captions. Should they be captions for figures or for subfigures?

Comment: @Vivian I updated my answer showing how to add subcaptions. Please let me know of this is what you need or if you need captions (not subcaptions) for the figures.

Comment: Hello. I copy your latex code. It works well. But I can not use in my template even I include the same packages. I don't know why. But the first one is enough for me.